# In Django ORM, how does one get_or_create for values in JSONField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-jsonfield

I am having a Django model like:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(default=dict)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
data = {"product_id": 123, "available": False}
subscription, new = Subscription.objects.get_or_create(data__product_id=123, 
data__available=False)
```

I tried doing the above but it just set the field as empty dictionary.

Comment: try this subscription, new = Subscription.objects.get_or_create(product_id=data['product_id'], 
available=data['available'])

Comment: why you are using __ two undersocres instead of one ?

Comment: I believe you're looking for this `Subscription.objects.get_or_create(data=data)`

Comment: just put  `data=data` in `get_or_create()`

Comment: `Subscription.objects.get_or_create(data={'product_id': 123, available=False})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
models.py :-
class Subscription(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(db_index=True,null=True)

views.py:-
DictToStore = {"product_id": 123, "available": False}
subscription, new = Subscription.objects.get_or_create(data=DictToStore)
```